# Como definir uma Tray Icon (ícone na bandeja) numa aplicação PyQt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt-4

Ainda sou iniciante em PyQt e gostaria de esclarecer uma dúvida:

Existe alguma forma de se definir um Tray Icon (Ícone na Bandeja) em uma aplicação PyQt?  Se tem, como eu posso fazer?

Preciso definir algumas opções nesse ícone de bandeja. Tem como fazer isso também?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classe `QSystemTrayIcon` serve para isto.

> http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html

Supondo que sua aplicação seja `qApp`, eis um pequeno exemplo:

```
trayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon( QtGui.QIcon('icone.png' ), qApp)
trayIcon.setTooltip('eu sou um ícone de bandeja')

sair = menu.addAction("Sair")
menu = QtGui.QMenu()

trayIcon.setContextMenu(menu)
trayIcon.show()
```

Pontos de interesse:

- `setTooltip` serve para definir a "dica" que aparece, por exemplo, quando você passa o mouse sobre o ícone;
- `setContextMenu`, como o nome já diz, serve para adicionar um menu de contexto ao ícone. Consulte a documentação do `QMenu` para mais detalhes;

Se quiser animar o ícone, pode fazer chamadas para o método `setIcon(const QIcon & icon)`, usando um `QTimer`, por exemplo. Só convém não querer fazer nada muito complexo, para não sacrificar a responsividade do OS.

Ainda, vale notar que existe o método `showMessage`, se quiser exibir uma mensagem para o usuário. Por exemplo, no Windows 7, é usado um balão:

[image: baloon tip]